# How can I get YOLOv4 inference times with OpenVINO that are as fast as OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, yolo, openvino

If I run a YoloV4 model with leaky relu activations on my CPU with 256x256 RGB images in OpenCV with an OpenVINO backend, inference time plus non-max suppression is about 80ms.  If, on the other hand, I convert my model to an IR following https://github.com/TNTWEN/OpenVINO-YOLOV4, which is linked to from https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet, inference time directly using the OpenVINO inference engine is roughly 130ms, which does not even include non-max suppression, which is quite slow when implemented naively in python.

Unfortunately, OpenCV does not offer all of the control I would like for the models and inference schemes I want to try (e.g. I want to change batch size, import models from YOLO repositories other than darknet, etc.)

What is the magic that allows OpenCV with OpenVINO backend to be so much faster?

Answer (score 2):

Inference performance is application dependent and subject to many variables such as model size, model architecture, processors, etc.

[This benchmark result](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/openvino_docs_performance_benchmarks_openvino.html#yolo_v4_tf_608x608) shows performance results of running [yolo-v4-tf](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_yolo_v4_tf.html) on multiple Intel® CPUs, GPUs and VPUs.

For example, you may use an [11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11850HE @ 2.60GHz CPU](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/217379/intel-core-i711850he-processor-24m-cache-up-to-4-70-ghz.html) to run [yolo-v4-tf](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_yolo_v4_tf.html), which gives 80.4 ms inferencing time.

[yolo-v4-tf](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_yolo_v4_tf.html) and [yolo-v4-tiny-tf](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_model_yolo_v4_tiny_tf.html) are [public pre-trained models](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_models_group_public.html) that you can use for learning and demo purposes or for developing deep learning software. You may download these models using [Model Downloader](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/omz_tools_downloader.html).